# What does the verb "architect" mean?

Tags: verbing, architecture

Here is a quote: "x Consulting Group provides senior consultants to evaluate, architect and design stable and effective solutions and networks".  What more is it that the consultants are doing that is not already captured by evaluating and designing?

Comment: Nothing. It just sounds fancy.

Comment: @Edwin: I duplicate closevoted it as per your suggestion. Is "duplicate closevote" a verb and a noun? Seriously, I'm unclear as to what possible distinction the writer might be trying to make between ***to architect*** and ***to design***. Perhaps it would make more sense if one were to be replaced by ***implement***.

Comment: @FF I've asked the writer (Richard Warner) of what I consider the best answer at the duplicate to expand upon this. He already mentions that there are points of non-overlap, at least in the way they use the verbs. I've asked for supporting material. (4 mins after your comment, but I've just realised that adding the naming parenthetical demands that 'they' be changed to 'he'.)

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please remember that one of the requirements of our site is that you demonstrate your initial research, for example, the results of a [dictionary lookup](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/architect). It's okay if the search was fruitless, but it's important so that we do not waste time duplicating your efforts. In the event, of course, you would have had your answer. I encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for further guidance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tradition of using professional titles as verbs in English (or vice versa), for example

> To doctor a report, to lord (over) one's subjects, to butcher one's
>   enemy, to tailor a suit, to engineer a solution...

I am an architect of buildings. The title of 'architect' has been adopted by the software community, normally used to define a role that (in my understanding) involves the structural design of IT systems - the clever thinking behind the way they work. To me, in this context, the difference between the terms is:

To Evaluate: Study the needs of the client, prepare a brief and a plan of action,

To Architect: Design and develop the structure for the solution/network, including the 'back-end' or 'server-side' programming,

To Design: To arrive at a 'polished' solution including many aspects of design, including consideration of User Interface, User Experience, Graphic design, etc.